# Does announcer badge count links to answers?

Tags: support, badges

I've noticed the badge for Announcer reads:

> Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses

Does this mean sharing links to answers does not qualify for the badge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can win an Announcer badge for sharing a link to an answer. As proof, I was awarded an Announcer badge on June 7 for [Regular expression pattern not matching anywhere in string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/1288) after [tweeting a link to the top answer](https://twitter.com/lizardbill/status/475066774547750912) on June 6.